# What permission to be added in app.json for CAMERA_ROLL in app.json for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

In my Application I'm using **expo-image-picker** to pick image to update the user's profile picture.
I had done the implementation. while implementing I used CAMERA_ROLL as type to check the permissions for Gallery.

By Default Expo is includes all permissions [link](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-stores/#android-permissions). I don't need that. I need to use only CAMER_ROLL as permission. I went through the [app.json configuration](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#android) docs but there, I can't find CAMER_ROLL or GALLERY related permissions.

What permission to be added in app.json for CAMERA_ROLL ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in app.json android.permissions = ['READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE', 'MANAGE_DOCUMENTS']

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar scenario. CAMERA_ROLL permission is all about reading and writing to the storage memory. So, it requires below Android permission needs to be added in app.json

> **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

> **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**

Comment: If I only need to access the camera roll to upload to my app, why would I need write permissions? I'm not disagreeing with this (since I have been struggling with this for the past 3 days) I'm just curious what the logic is.